# How to use XML for object representation in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

First I just want to preface this with that I have never used XML or C# prior to this so I apologize if my questions don't make sense.

I have been tasked with modifying an existing C# program.

What the program currently does is it reads in a text file that has entries such as:

employee ID-Name-Supervisor ID

```
7;Jill;0
3;Joe;7
6;Bob;3
```

Where the text above corresponds to Employee-Supervisor relationships, so for example, Joe's employee ID is 3 and he reports to Jill.  Bob's employee's ID is 6 and he reports to Joe.

I've written a program in Java that takes the above text files and turns them into an XML file like so (following the above example):

```
<Employees>
  <Employee_Name> Jill
           <Employee_Name>Joe 
                 <Employee_Name>Bob</Employee_Name>
           </Employee_Name>
   </Employee_Name>
</Employees>
```

My issue is the following:

How can I take this XML hierarchy and make it something usable for my C# program, where it is aware of the relationships?

For example, one of the functions would be to have the program send an email automatically to all of the employee's supervisors, and to anyone supervised by the same direct manager.

Thank you!

Comment: @MStodd how is it exactly not XML?

Comment: It's got text and tags embedded together.  It is not valid XML.

Comment: An XML node can either contain a value, or an element, but not both.

Comment: Actually, it is! And it's event parsed right using `XElement.Parse()`

Comment: Why are you running the data through a Java program first?  Why not just parse it in the C# program?

Comment: Is mine not similarly formatted to this? [link](http://www.functionx.com/csharp/xml/Lesson02.htm)

I'm a bit confused to why my XML is incorrect. 

Thanks.

Comment: @MStodd Does it matter that I created my XML file using Java?

Comment: No, but it seems like initially there was a C# program to read in a file and process it.  Now there a Java program to read in the file, then output a file for the C# program to process.  Why not skip the Java program?

Comment: Perhaps I'll look into that later but right now this issue is more pressing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to XML to query your document:

First of all, you need a class to store data:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee>  Subordinates { get; set; }

}
```

Then, you can use `XElement.Parse()` to parse your xml string or `XElement.Load(filePath)` to load it from file.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<Employees>  <Employee_Name> Jill           <Employee_Name>Joe                  <Employee_Name>Bob</Employee_Name>           </Employee_Name>   </Employee_Name></Employees>");
```

And recursive algorithm to get data:

```
static List<Employee> GetEmployees(XElement xml)
{
    return (from e in xml.Elements("Employee_Name")
            let name = e.Nodes().First().ToString()
            select new Employee { Name = name, Subordinates = GetEmployees(e) }).ToList();
}
```

Which can be called on your xml:

```
var employees = GetEmployees(xml);
```

For your sample data you'll receive one Employee (Jill) with one subordinate (Joe), which would have another subordinate (Bob) too.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you. I am looking into this.

Comment: Hi, I'm having an issue. This line: 
select new Employee { Name = name, Subordinates = GetEmployees(e) }).ToList();



It's saying GetEmployees doesn't exist in the current context.